# Convert dictionary to array - Swift 5

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following dictionary:

```
@Published var walletsTokenData: [Wallet: [TokenBalanceClassAModel]] = [:]
```

Once I populate the value from the API, I want to iterate through each Wallet element, call it `a, b, c`. The problem is that diccionaries are unorder and I need to do a lot of iterations and searching in my views so I thought a better idea is instead of having a diccionary, having an array so I'm also able to do in the view `ForEach(walletsTokenData.address) { address in`

How can I convert that diccionary into an array?

I tried something like:

```
@Published var x: [[[Wallet][TokenBalanceClassAModel]] = []
```

but it just looks weird. Is that even correct? I need to be able to link 1 wallet (I called it `a` above) to multiple items, then `b` to multiple items but a and b and their items being unrelated.

I understand I have a weak spot in data structures, that's why I'm seeking help :)

I tried this for the dictionary:

```
ForEach(walletsTokenData.keys, id: \.self) { key in
```

but it says:

```
Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Dictionary<Wallet, [TokenBalanceClassAModel]>.Keys' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'
```

I just think an array would make more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to iterate through each Wallet element in a sorted way, you could try this:

```
ForEach(walletsTokenData.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { wallet in

...
}
```

you can customise your sorting with, for example:

```
ForEach(walletsTokenData.keys.sorted(by: {$0.value < $1.value}), id: \.self)
```

where value just represents whatever you want to sort the wallets by. Note you will need to make Wallet Hashable.

EDIT 1: here is an example:

```
struct Wallet {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var address: String
    var amount: Double
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var walletsTokenData: [Wallet: [String]] = [
        Wallet(address: "Wallet1 address", amount: 5.0):["zzz"],
        Wallet(address: "Wallet2 address", amount: 2.0):["xxx"]]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(walletsTokenData.keys.sorted(by: {$0.amount < $1.amount}), id: \.id) { wallet in
                Text(wallet.address)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to make Wallet Identifiable and Hashable add this:

```
extension Wallet: Identifiable, Hashable { }
```

Comment: how do I know for which key it's being sorted? In an array when you append it you know the order, how is it going to sort it in this case? Is it by letter, by number, by what? Also it says: `Referencing instance method 'sorted()' on 'Sequence' requires that 'Dictionary<Wallet, [TokenBalanceClassAModel]>.Keys.Element' (aka 'Wallet') conform to 'Comparable'`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Show us the code for Wallet and which variable you want to sort them by.

Comment: I can't modify wallet and make it Hashable it's autogenerated, it looks like: `struct Wallet: Model {
  public let id: String
  public var address: String ... }`

Comment: I had to do a couple of things besides that but now the Dictionary is working magically, thanks accepted and +1

Comment: How can I iterate in the ForEach without the sort()? Like print the items in the same order they were added to the diccionary?

Comment: just do this: `ForEach(Array(walletsTokenData.keys))`